# Remove text result from SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i have this code :

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(angsuran) FROM `laporan` WHERE id_mustahik=".$detail_campaigner->id_mustahik."");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

when i run this code, the result is :

```
Array ( [SUM(angsuran)] => 30000 )
```

But i want it to display just "30000" number, without "Array ( [SUM(angsuran)] =>  ) ".

How can i do that ?

Comment: `$row["SUM(angsuran)"]` might do.

Comment: thanks it work, it so simple :)

Comment: using alias is a little cleaner: `SUM(angsuran) as sum`  and then `$row['sum']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**add alias in your query like**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(angsuran) as sumtotal FROM `laporan` WHERE id_mustahik=".$detail_campaigner->id_mustahik."");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['sumtotal']; //outputs 30000
```

Answer (score -1):

I have 2 ways

Use array php

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(angsuran) FROM `laporan` WHERE id_mustahik=".$detail_campaigner->id_mustahik."");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row["SUM(angsuran)"]; // out 30000
```

Modify sql

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(angsuran) as sum FROM `laporan` WHERE id_mustahik=".$detail_campaigner->id_mustahik."");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row["sum"]; // out 30000
```

Comment: Thanks for your support